# Boxplot: Extract outliers and tag them as either '0' or '1'

Tags: python, loops, boxplot

I'm trying to extract outliers from my dataset and tag them accordingly.

Sample Data

```
     Doctor Name    Hospital Assigned         Region    Claims   Illness Claimed
1    Albert      Some hospital Center      R-1       20       Sepsis
2    Simon       Another hospital Center   R-2       21       Pneumonia
3    Alvin       ...                       ...       ...       ...
4    Robert
5    Benedict
6    Cruz
```

So I'm trying to group every `Doctor` that `Claimed` a certain `Illness` in a certain `Region` and trying to find outliers among them.

```
Doctor Name    Hospital Assigned         Region    Claims   Illness Claimed is_outlier
1    Albert      Some hospital Center      R-1       20       Sepsis       1
2    Simon       Another hospital Center   R-2       21       Pneumonia    0
3    Alvin       ...                       ...       ...       ...
4    Robert
5    Benedict
6    Cruz
```

I can do this in Power BI. But being fairly new to Python, I can't seem to figure this out.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: sample]

Algo goes like:

```
Read data
Group data by Illness
    Group by Region
    get IQR based on Claims Count
    if claims count > than (Q3 + 1.5) * IQR
        then tag it as outlier = 1
    else
        not an outlier = 0
Export data
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use pandas for data analysis (and you should!) You can use pandas dataframe boxplot to produce a plot similar to yours:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.boxplot(column=['b'], whis=[10, 90], vert=False, 
           flierprops=dict(markerfacecolor='g', marker='D'))
```

or, if you want to mark them 0,1 as you requested, use dataframe quantile() method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

```
df.assign(outlier=df[df>=df.quantile(.9)].any(axis=1)).astype(np.int8)
    a   b   outlier
0   1   1   0
1   2   10  0
2   3   100     1
3   4   100     1
```

Comment: Unfortunately the second code doesn't work for `string` data type. I get an error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

Comment: That's right, compare only numbers. If you need to find outliers in number of claimes, may be you first aggregate your data, i.e. df.groupby('Doctor Name').size().to_frame().boxplot(...)

Comment: or use df[df>=df['Claims'].quantile(0.9)] construct to limit looking for outliers in 'Claims' column only

Comment: I added an algorithm for clarity